# Linux can not detect Altera FPGA

Tags: linux, usb, fpga, jtag, intel-fpga

Well, i have an Altera FPGA and USB blaster. I downloaded quartus, but it doesn't detect FPGA, i tried with urjtag and it works fine. I tried running it with sudo, but again the same. Help please

Comment: This is off-topic here, this site is for programming questions. Try either electronics.stackexchange.com or superuser.com, I'm not sure which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be good if this question could be moved.

Here is a link to a site with instructions on this problem: http://www.fpga-dev.com/altera-usb-blaster-with-ubuntu/

In short, since Quartus will typically attempt to use the USB device as a user, nu must give the user permissions to use the device. This can be accomplished by udev rules. You can at first confirm that this is a permission problem by running the following sequence of commands. If devices are found now, this indicates a permission problem since we have now been running everything as root:

```
    $ sudo killall -9 jtagd   # Kill jtagd, ...
    $ sudo killall -9 jtagd   # ...and verify jtagd is indeed not running.
    jtagd: no process found   # Good, verified.
    $ jtagconfig
    1) CV SoCKit [2-1]
      02D020DD   5CSEBA6(.|ES)/5CSEMA6/..
      4BA00477   SOCVHPS
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tim here, the question should be asked on another location, your problem is probably because of a the driver of USB blaster is not installed properly. Try to do a search on internet and see if you can find any similar problems, or go to Altera forum and ask the question there, there are many experienced users there who are familiar with this kinds of problems.